# Create a 3D map using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking for a way to create a picture like the attached one using Ti*k*Z package.

I have data file for Amplitude versus Frequence at various abscissa *x*. 
Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Yes, pgfplots allows you to produce such diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

This is taken almost literally from the pgfplots manual except that I deferred the data to a external file (and swapped the roles of x and y). This is to demonstrate that yes, it can be done with pgfplots, and how we usually exchange codes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
a b 
-3 9 
-2 4 
-1 1 
0 0 
1 1 
2 4 
3 9
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=6,extra x ticks={4,5},
    extra x tick style={xticklabel=\empty,grid=major}]
    \addplot3[no marks,color=blue] table [x=a,y expr=2,z=b] {data.txt};
    \addplot3[no marks,color=red] table [x=a,y expr=4,z=b] {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]